# Modifying R code for getting the augmented coefficient matrix for 5 or more equations and unknown variables

Tags: r, matrix, data-science, gaussian, coefficients

Can anyone help me in modifying this code? I am stuck in this ever since last week. I am trying to make this code work for these following equations yet nothing works.

<strike>Also, I am doing this so I can create 2 R functions for Gaussian elimination and Gauss-Jordan elimination. If you are knowledgeable with this, can you help me with it too? Thank you!</strike>

Each function (Gauss and Gauss-Jordan) should return a labelled list containing the following:

- variables: this is a vector containing the unknown variables
- augcoeffmatrix: this is the last snapshot of the transformed augmented coefficient matrix
- solution: a vector containing the solution (i.e. the value for each unknown)

If the system has no solution or has an infinite number of solutions, solution should be
NA.

*These are the equations that I am trying to work with:*

```
# E1 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 8000 * x1 + 4500 * x2 + 4000 * x3 + 3000 * x4 + 2000 * x5 + 1000 * x6 + 900 * x7 + 250 * x8 + -143145000
# E2 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 7800 * x1 + 6500 * x2 + 5800 * x3 + 0 * x4 + 3100 * x5 + 1600 * x6 + 1000 * x7 + 300 * x8 + -58870000
# E3 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 10000 * x1 + 0 * x2 + 3100 * x3 + 0 * x4 + 2600 * x5 + 1300 * x6 + 850 * x7 + 150 * x8 + -108440000
# E4 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 5200 * x1 + 3700 * x2 + 3100 * x3 + 2700 * x4 + 2400 * x5 + 1800 * x6 + 1200 * x7 + 450 * x8 + -143805000
# E5 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 7700 * x1 + 7100 * x2 + 0 * x3 + 5700 * x4 + 5100 * x5 + 1300 * x6 + 950 * x7 + 95 * x8 + -181390500
# E6 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 9300 * x1 + 8700 * x2 + 6100 * x3 + 5100 * x4 + 4000 * x5 + 1000 * x6 + 700 * x7 + 70 * x8 + -209273000
# E7 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 6000 * x1 + 0 * x2 + 5000 * x3 + 4300 * x4 + 3000 * x5 + 1900 * x6 + 1400 * x7 + 920 * x8 + -174388000
# E8 <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) 8500 * x1 + 3700 * x2 + 4200 * x3 + 3900 * x4 + 3500 * x5 + 2400 * x6 + 1000 * x7 + 250 * x8 + -183065000
```

**THESE IS THE AUGMENTED COEFFICIENT MATRIX CODE:**

```
# Define the equations as functions
E1 <- function(x1, x2, x3) 25 * x1 + 5 * x2 + 1 * x3 + -106.8
E2 <- function(x1, x2, x3) 64 * x1 + 8 * x2 + 1 * x3 + -177.2
E3 <- function(x1, x2, x3) 144 * x1 + 12 * x2 + 1 * x3 + -279.2

system <- list(E1, E2, E3)

AugCoeffMatrix <- function(system){
  
  # Check if the number of unknown variables is equal for all equations in the system.
  numOfVar <- sapply(system, function(eq)length(formals(eq)))
  if (length(unique(numOfVar)) != 1) {
    return(NA)
  }
  
  # Check if the number of equations is less than the number of unknown variables.
  if (length(system) < numOfVar[1]) {
    return(NA)
  }
  
  # Initialize an empty character vector named "variables" to store the variable names.
  variables <- character(0)
  
  # Create a matrix named "augcoeffmatrix" with dimensions based on the length of the system.
  augcoeffmatrix <- matrix(0, length(system), length(system)+1)
  
  # Iterate over each equation in the system.
  for (count in 1:length(system)){
    
    # Retrieving the equation string representation using the "deparse" function.
    equation <- deparse(system[[count]])
    
    # Extracting the variable names from the equation string.
    variables <- gsub("function","",equation[1])
    variables <- gsub(" ", "", variables)
    variables <- gsub("\\(","",variables) #Because parentheses must be escaped with double backslashes because they are special characters in regular expressions, the pattern "\\(" is employed.
    variables <- gsub("\\)","",variables)
    variables <- strsplit(variables,",")
    
    # Creating column names for the augmented coefficient matrix. These are the variable names plus "RHS" to represent the right-hand side.
    colnames(augcoeffmatrix) <- c(variables[[1]], "RHS")
    
    # Creating row names for the augmented coefficient matrix. These are the numbers from 1 to the length of the system.
    rownames(augcoeffmatrix) <- 1:length(system)
    
    # Split the equation string into individual terms using the "+" delimiter.
    terms <- strsplit(equation[2]," \\+")
    
    # Iterate (using for loop) over each term in the equation.
    for (i in terms[[1]]){
      
      # Check if the term contains a multiplication operator "*".
      if (grepl("*",i,fixed=TRUE)){
        
        # Split the term into coefficient and variable parts using the "*" delimiter.
        coeff <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(i,"\\*")))
        
        # Updating the corresponding entry in the augmented coefficient matrix with the numeric value of the coefficient.
        augcoeffmatrix[count,coeff[[2]]] <- as.numeric(coeff[[1]])
        
      }else{
        
        # If the term does not contain a multiplication operator, it represents a constant value on the right-hand side of the equation.
        # Multiply the constant value by -1 and update the "RHS" column of the matrix.
        augcoeffmatrix[count, "RHS"] <- as.numeric(i)*-1
      }
    }
  }
  
  result <- list("variables" = variables[[1]], "augcoefmatrix" = augcoeffmatrix)
  
  return(result)
}

result1 = AugCoeffMatrix(system)
print(result1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using deparse to break the function into textual parts. but linebreaks are hurting you. you can dodge that with

```
    equation <- deparse(system[[count]],width.cutoff = 500)
```